# How to get status of the user like online, offline or away(inactive for some time) in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico

I want to display the status of a user.If the user will be online then I have to show green icon on the user profile.If a user will be offline then I have to show grey icon and it might be possible that user will be logged in but not active in that case I have to display orange icon(for the idle user) on the profile.

I have to implement this feature in ASP.NET.

Comment: Is this for a web application or a windows application?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that out of the box using Kentico, first you have to enable Online Users module, to track all the online users also you will have the ability to kick any user for limited amount of time (configurable)

after you do that you can use the code at kentico documentation

https://docs.kentico.com/api10/configuration/users#Users-Checkingifauserisonline

Comment: I can check user in Kentico that user is online or offline but the main problem is to get the idle state of a user. like how I will implement that in Kentico.


in the current scenario, if the user will be online but not moving his/her cursor or mouse click till a certain amount of time on the website, in that case, I have to display that user as idle.

Comment: this scenario doesn't exist in kentico out of the box features, you have to make some customization

Answer (score 0):

In Kentico 11, (and I presume older versions), there are three DateTime fields on the CMS_Session table, `SessionLastActive`, `SessionLastLogon`, and `SessionExpires`. You can use the API to get online users, (https://docs.kentico.com/api11/configuration/users#Users-Onlineusers), or just do the whole thing including both users and the pertinent DateTimes from a [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure), [Kentico Query](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/loading-data-using-custom-queries), or any other method used to [query the database](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/miscellaneous-custom-development-tasks/working-with-database-queries-in-the-api).

Comment: Stephen or Satyam, Did you have any luck resolving this issue?